# $scope variable not rendering in view

Tags: angularjs

I am getting started with angularjs and started working on a simple example. Overall I didn't ran into big challenges so far but this one i couldn't figure out... I have some $scope variables defined like this:

```
    'use strict';
angular.module('portalApp')
    .controller('summaryController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.todayProduction = '8';
        $scope.yesterdayProduction = '20';
        $scope.monthlyProduction = '500';
        $scope.dockedVessels = '16';
    }]);
```

and this is my view html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" style="font-size: 50px;float: right;"></span>
                    <div>Today's Production</div>
                    <div style="font-size: 24px;">{{todayProduction}}<span style="font-size: 12px;"> tons</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" style="font-size: 50px;float: right;"></span>
                    <div>Yesterdays's Production</div>
                    <div style="font-size: 24px;">{{yesterdayProduction}}<span style="font-size: 12px;"> tons</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" style="font-size: 50px;float: right;"></span>
                    <div>Monthly Production</div>
                    <div style="font-size: 24px;">{{monthlyProduction}}<span style="font-size: 12px;"> tons</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" style="font-size: 50px;float: right;"></span>
                    <div>Docked Vessels</div>
                    <div style="font-size: 24px;">{{dockedVessels}}<span style="font-size: 12px;"> tons</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when rendering I see the glyphicon as expected but instead of displaying the variable values I get "{{variableName}}" for all of them.

As a background the sample project I am using was originally for 1.5 version but I'm running a 1.6

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: how is your view attached to controller? do you use directive?

Comment: sorry, this is my app.js

Comment: Code goes in your question, not in the comments

Comment: open up dev tools F12 and look into console, the error will tell you what you missed. most likely controller is not registered in index.html file

Comment: thanks! i found that there was a problem with variable {{monthlyProduc tion}} because of the space but after removing the space I'm still getting the same error... any ideas as of why the change would not reflect? I've even tried removing the whole code and replacing it but in VS the variable looks good but in the site doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Change **{{monthlyProduc tion}}** to **{{monthlyProduction}}** in your html.